# Content sensitive title for aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a Sharepoint project with a lot of different aspx-pages I have to deal with, but my ASP.net knowledge is still limited. Basically the web application's core is based on userdata. Let's keep it simple and just assume that you can select different userdata and the aspx-pages will render the content based on it.

Now it's not always easy to keep track of all the tabs in your browser. As a solution, the browser tab should render the username in its title besides other (static) information. My current solution is to set the title programatically with the help of [this](http://chris.gg/2010/02/how-to-set-sharepoint-page-title-programmatically/) post. As a result, this is what I have so far:

The already existing aspx-pages retrieve some static string from a resource file to render the static part of the title.

```
<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
  <asp:Literal runat="server" text="<%$Resources:UserManager.Resource,GeneralPageTitle%>">                
  </asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
```

Now it's my part to adjust the title by the selected user content. My code-behind does the neccessary stuff in the Page_Load function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // (...) some stuff happening here

    if (Page.Master != null)
    {
        var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        var contentPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderPageTitle");
        if (contentPlaceHolder == null) return;

        string oldText = String.Empty;
        foreach (var control in contentPlaceHolder.Controls)
        {
            var textControl = control as ITextControl;
            if (textControl != null)
            {
                oldText += textControl.Text;
            }
        }

        contentPlaceHolder.Controls.Clear();

        var literalControl = new LiteralControl();
        var userName = web.GetCurrentUserName();
        literalControl.Text = String.Format("{0} - {1}", oldText, userName);
        contentPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(literalControl);
    }
}
```

Of course, since there are a lot of different aspx-pages, you would not put this code into each Page_Load function because of code duplicity. But for this example it'll do the trick.

Basically, yes, this works. BUT it's a bit hacky. Furthermore I still don't like the idea of editing all the aspx's code-behind files (there are lots of them). I'd rather prefer a cleaner solution. Is there any way of achieving the same goal differently?

**Update**

With the help of SazooCat I found out that you could also add code behind to your custom masterpage ([see this](http://blog.nerdery.com/2013/04/tech-tips-creating-a-sharepoint-2010-master-page-with-code-behind/)). Well, that works, too. And I only have to edit a single file. Is this good practice or a NoGo?

Comment: Updated the question with an alternative solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the route I am going now, because it fits my needs the best.

First I created a custom User Control

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="BrowserTabInfo.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls.BrowserTabInfo" %>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="userName"></asp:Literal>
```

that executes some code-behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    if (web == null) return;

    var userName = web.GetCurrentUserName();
    userName.Text = "- " + userName;
}
```

And then the User Control is inserted into the master page.

```
<title id="onetidTitle"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/><browsertabinfo:BrowserTabInfoControl id="browsertabinfo" runat="server"/></title>
```

Even if there will be a different master page someday, you just have to insert the user control into that master page again to get the same functionality. And you only have to touch (basically) one file instead of dozens of content pages.

Answer (score 0):

You know you can do (in code behind) `Page.Title = "My custom title string"` right?

Oh, and if it is a common construction of some properties, if you make a class

```
public class MyCustomBasePage Inherits Page
```

Then in THERE put in the `Page.Title = ???` bit in an OnLoad event

Then each of your content pages can inherit from MyCustomBasePage
e.g.

```
Public class MyExamplecontentPage Inherits MyCustomBasePage
```

Following up from comments... if you're setting a default title at master page level and an override title and content page level then you need to read this other entry: [How to set Page's Title from a web content page in ASP.NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293342/how-to-set-pages-title-from-a-web-content-page-in-asp-net-3-5)

Comment: Setting Page.Title doesn't work for me. At least not in Page_Load(), where it has no effect. And yes, the pages could inherit. But I would still have to touch each code-behind file to make them inherit, so it would give me no real advantage.

Comment: You don't currently have a common base class you could extend?

Comment: In answer as to why your content Page.Title isn't working is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293342/how-to-set-pages-title-from-a-web-content-page-in-asp-net-3-5

Comment: There is no custom base class. This would make it an easy task, but no, nothing like that.

Comment: Your link helped me to find another way of doing it, by providing a code-behind to the custom master page itself. But I don't know if you _should_ do something like this.

Comment: Personally I'd go down the common base class route, but I understand you're not keen on the effort required to go back over all the pages.  In a content management system scenario it would be common shared code reading properties to set page titles (though more likely page classes than master pages it is possible to do it there if the master page is only used in this context).

Comment: Seems you are right. Asked someone related to my company who basically said the same and that you would not use code-behind in a master page in SharePoint.